Find out function address in the disassembled binary using MDMP

I have a log file from the target Linux machine stating where crash has occured:
0x00000000046195d3 MyApp!UnknownFunction(0x44195d3)

I have fully analyzed and disassembled in IDA MyApp binary

I also have MDMP file from the target machine


Now, obviously I can't just go to 0x00000000046195d3 in the disassembled binary because it wont be a correct offset. Is there any way I can use information from minidump to adjust offset so it matches in IDA too?
P.S. I dont have not dont want to use windbg or x64dbg - every single google result leads to these

Why don't you check the other address 0x44195d3? Normally it is the address within the bentioned binary without any AS OR or other relocation offsets.

It also leads to nonsense section that has no assembly data
